# ListBox get value from index

Tags: c#, listbox

I am writing a program where you insert some numbers in a listbox and then a button click should get the values from the listbox and check whether they are positive or negative and display each other's count in a textbox.
I tried getting the value by: `string x = listBox1.Items[index].Value;` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How are you putting the data into the ListBox Items?

Comment: by a button: `listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the items to the list box as such:

`listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);`

Then you can retrieve the item from given index as follows:

`string x = listBox1.Items[index];`

The indexer is returning the value, which in that case is a string. Probably you might need to cast it to string, because the indexer actually returns object - see here: [ListBox.ObjectCollection.Item Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

`string x = (string)listBox1.Items[index];`

Comment: Thank you. It gets the item at the certain index but now I am kind of lost with how to display the count of negative/positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
string s = (string)listbox1.Items.GetItemAt(index);
```

You have to cast it to string because it's returning an object